# How to fill the shape, made up of GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: c++, opengl, line, wave, sine-wave

I'm trying to make do water simulation. But I'm restricted to use 2D, So i started with just making the boundary of the sea by using sine wave, through Gl_Line_loop. but I'm just unable to fill it. I have tried changing it to the Gl_polygon mode but then i don't get the proper shape. here is the code:

[here is the image of wave, i want to get filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V6KM.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tessellate the above, specify a top then a bottom vertex right along the line, then draw a triangle strip.  i.e. for each (x, y) position along the sin wave, emit two vertices, the same x but y = 0 (the bottom).  Then render a triangle strip.

Something like this:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
for(x=-50;x<=50;x+=inc){
    k = 2 * 3.14 / wavelength;
    y = amplitude * sin(k * x);
    glVertex3f(x, y-35, 0);
    glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: Can you please also suggest me way to animate it in such a way that it looks like water is flowing ??

Comment: The wavelength angle for an x position is fixed from -50 to 50 as sin(k * x).  You need k * x to be changing over time so perhaps sin(k * (x + t)), where t starts at 0 say, and increments by a small amount each frame.

Comment: You sir are a genius :'D it's movingg.. thankss again :')